# How i can get total Download figures for Wifi and GPRS (GSM) separately for iPhone / iPad

Tags: ios

How to get total downloaded bytes figures and how i can come to know that how many bytes are downloaded using wifi and how many using GSM (iPhone + iPad)?

**Thanks in advance.**

**Muzammal Hussain.**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the following delegate method of NSURLConnection :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
// Append the new data to receivedData.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
[receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

In this way you get the NSData in one variable. Then you can get its size in the delegate method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

OR

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

With help of the line:

```
NSLog(@"Data downloaded==%d",receivedData.length);
```

Hope this helps.